# Left censored dependent variable in SEM

Tags: survival, structural-equation-modeling, censoring, amos, nonlinearity

I'm working on a structural equation model in `Amos`. I have two independent variables, 5 mediators and a left censored dependent variable. The dependent variable is either 0 or a positive amount in euros.

My question is: is there a way in `Amos` to analyze such a model in which the dependent is non-linear? And if not, is there another SEM-package that can?

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way in Amos to analyze such a model in which the dependent is non-linear?

While `AMOS` can handle censored data (see the `AMOS` [manual](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/its/pdfs/SPSS_Amos_User_Guide_22.pdf) pages 475-488), its functionality in this respect is quite limited, as the software appears to be focused on linear structural equation models (SEM), and I don't believe it can handle left-censored data.

> And if not, is there another SEM-package that can?

Regarding other software packages, I know `STATA` (see [here](https://is%20there%20a%20way%20in%20Amos%20to%20analyse%20such%20a%20model%20in%20which%20the%20dependent%20is%20non-linear?)) and `Mplus`$^1$ can handle left-censored data.

$^1$ See [this](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/mplus/dae/tobit-analysis/) link for an intro to tobit (i.e., censored) regression in `Mplus`. I am not sure though it `Mplus` can handle left-censored data.